# In IIS, is there a way to limit how many times a particular file can be served?

Tags: iis

My webpage automatically creates a .pdf file and a link to go with it.  I want the user to be able to download the file from the link-- but only once (or maybe 5x or whatever I decide later).

Is there any easy way in IIS of limiting the number of times files in a particular folder are served before requests will be refused?

Comment: Yeah, I think I'll have a download page with a GUID querystring, and just check the access time against creation date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no relevant configuration in IIS that can limit the number of user downloads.
You can completely implement your needs in your program. Add the code to count the number of downloads by the currently logged in user. Restrict users according to the limit times you set.